# Solr facet date count wrong?

Tags: date, solr, faceted-search

I issue this facet date url:

```
 http://10.18.1.85:8080/mcu1fpSE/articleCore/select/?q=*:*&rows=0&indent=true&facet=true&facet.date=PRESENTDATE&facet.date.start=2011-12-01T00:00:00Z&facet.date.end=2012-06-01T23:59:59Z&facet.date.gap=%2B1MONTH
```

The result is:

```
  <int name="2011-12-01T00:00:00Z">250</int>
  <int name="2012-01-01T00:00:00Z">8360</int>
  <int name="2012-02-01T00:00:00Z">9032</int>
  <int name="2012-03-01T00:00:00Z">7332</int>
  <int name="2012-04-01T00:00:00Z">9497</int>
  <int name="2012-05-01T00:00:00Z">10210</int>
  <int name="2012-06-01T00:00:00Z">9789</int>
```

However, when I issue following query in admin ui:

```
PRESENTDATE:[2011-12-01T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-31T00:00:00Z]
```

There's no any doc returned.

Does Solr Facet Date functionality counts wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried date faceting in Solr 4.2.1 and it is not returning correct values. It has been deprecated like the [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting_Parameters) says. Instead I tried [range faceting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#rangefaceting) and it works fine:

`q=*:*&wt=json&rows=0&facet=true&facet.range=PRESENTDATE&facet.range.start=2011-12-01T00:00:00Z&facet.range.end=2012-06-01T23:59:59Z&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH`